# Cesium Draw and Measure tools for 2D maps?

Tags: maps, cesiumjs

I am using Cesium to display a strictly 2D map in the browser (wrapped in React using the Resium library).

I am interested in giving the user the option to draw lines\polygons, and to measure the distances between two points or the area withing the polygon.

**Basially, I want precisely this OpenLayeres example, but in Cesium**: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/measure.html

How would one go about doing it?

Thank you

Comment: This question is too broad as phrased here.  Generally you shouldn't ask folks on this site to build a complex web app in their answer.  Instead, try building it on your own, and post specific questions here (or look for existing answers) when you run into problems.  Your app will need to respond to user clicks by placing points, and it will need to measure distances between those points.  All of those smaller actions already have examples online, here and elsewhere.  If you post your own version after building it, folks here can help debug it.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing some research on cesium drawing tool library. 
It wasn't same as the one you asked but you can use it for your need. you can use for 2D and 3D maps. it gives all basic functionalities like draw circle, polygon, add marker, draw line, calculate distance etc.

```
I have found cesium-draw the library for the VUE.
[cesium draw ](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cesium-draw)<br>
If you can work with Angular their is a lot of cesium sport in angular so you can use
[angular-cesium](https://angular-cesium.com/)
```

if you have found any thing else please do share I love to see.